# Как получить путь к папке приложения?

Tags: android

Андроид-приложение может быть установлено не только в папку `/data/data/...`, а в другое место, например, на флэшку. Как получить правильный путь к папке, в которую приложение реально установлено?

Comment: А зачем вам знать этот путь? Править своё приложение не стоит, а прочесть собственные файлы вы и так можете, так как они являются ресурсами приложения.

Comment: В папке lib лежат библиотеки, которые нужно динамически подгружать из другой библиотеки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Путь к папке приложения (java)

```
String path = getApplicationInfo().dataDir;
```

Но нужно учесть, что не всегда библиотеки будут в подпапке lib папки приложения. В случае, если приложение устанавливалось при изготовлении образа, apk будет в /system/apps, а so - в /system/lib/.

Answer (score 0):

Хм.. я не уверен, как в андроидном окружении, но просто под линуксом всегда есть возможность прочесть /proc/self/exe

```
#include <stdio.h>

static char buffer[4096];

int main(void) {
    readlink("/proc/self/exe", buffer, sizeof(buffer));
    printf("Iam here: %s\n", buffer);

    return 0;
}

cy6ergn0m@cgmachine test/cpp/procselfexe $ gcc main.c 
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine test/cpp/procselfexe $ ./a.out 
Iam here: /home/cy6ergn0m/test/cpp/procselfexe/a.out
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine test/cpp/procselfexe $
```

После всего, отрезать лишнее думаю уже не сложно

UPD: /proc/self/cwd не годится. Вот наглядный пример:

```
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine test/cpp/procselfexe $ ps ax | grep firefox
15925 pts/5    S+     0:00 grep --color firefox
23213 ?        Sl   474:33 /usr/bin/firefox
cy6ergn0m@cgmachine test/cpp/procselfexe $ stat /proc/23213/cwd
  File: «/proc/23213/cwd» -> «/home/cy6ergn0m/Документы»
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   символьная ссылка
Device: 3h/3d   Inode: 2871843     Links: 1
Access: (0777/lrwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (10001/cy6ergn0m)   Gid: (10001/cy6ergn0m)
Access: 2011-02-01 00:14:16.889605504 +0300
Modify: 2011-02-01 00:14:16.888555587 +0300
Change: 2011-02-01 00:14:16.888555587 +0300
```

Уж ясно, что firefox не лежит в /home/cy6ergn0m/Документы. Легко сделать ещё несколько проверок, чтобы окончательно убедиться в этом.

Comment: Зачем читать exe? Но пользуясь тем же подходом: /proc/self/cwd/

Comment: cwd? Ну и куда же ссылается cwd? Что-то я вижу, что он ссылается на просто на текущую директорию, а не на директорию приложения. И что значит "exe'шник" читать? Его никто не читает, а проверяется, куда ведёт ссылка.